# Uso de Model Classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, model

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto el cual está casi finalizado. La aplicación (por ahora) es muy sencilla, es una lista de objetos con nombre, descripción, etc. y la opción de pulsar cada elemento para entrar a ver la descripción completa. Logré hacer todo lo mencionado pero ahora necesitan que utilice una clase Model para el consumo/despliegue de datos.

Sé que tengo que crear una clase Java con cada elemento del JSON con sus getters y setters pero de ahí ya no tengo idea de como continuar. Alguien sabe de algún ejemplo para guiarme un poco? Este es el código que uso actualmente.

Normalmente creo el request en un AsyncTask y en el `onPostExecute`realizo el set de Adapter:

```
listView.setAdapter(new UsersAdapter(context, R.layout.user_list, jsonArray));
```

Luego tengo el Adapter

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
    Context context;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray) {
       this.context = context;
       this.jsonArray = jsonArray
    }

    public int getCount() {
       return this.jsonArray.length();
    }

    //codigo getView definimos todos los textos, imagen, etc
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list, null, false);
       v = new ViewHolder();
       ...
       ...
    }

    //usar valores del modelo en vez del código actual
    final JSONObject objActual = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
    v.nombreUsuario.setText(objActual.getString("name"));
    v.descripcion.setText(objActual.getString("description"));

    ...
    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

Mis dudas son las siguientes.

*Si tengo que utilizar una clase Model, mi Adapter `UsersAdapter` ya no deberia extender de `ArrayAdapter<JSONObject>`?

*Habría que hacer algún cambio en el Constructor y en el `getCount()`

*Cual sería la forma de desplegar un elemento json en los `TextView`? Estoy seguro de que esta forma `.setText(objActual.getString("nombreDelElemento"))` ya no sería la correcta. Además, es posible enviar los valores `"description"` a otra activity vía `Intent` para mostrarlos en otra pantalla?

La estructura del JSON es algo similar a esto:

```
[
  {
    "id":187,
    "name": "Market Casa Central",
    "description": "Te esperamos desde las...",
    "image": "url",
    "latlon": {
       "latitude": "0.0",
       "longitude": "0.0",
    }
    ...
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre tus dudas.

> Si tengo que utilizar una clase Model, mi Adapter UsersAdapter ya no
>   debería extender de ArrayAdapter?

R/. Exacto extendería de `ArrayAdapter<ModeloAImplementar>`. `ModeloAImplementar` puede ser la clase Usuario con las propiedades del json como mencionas arriba con set y get.

> *Habría que hacer algún cambio en el Constructor y en el getCount()

En el constructor en lugar de pasar un JSONArray puedes pasar un `ArrayList<ModeloAImplementar>` o un `List<ModeloAImplementar>` en el getCount harias `jsonArray.size()` recuerda hacer en el constructor this.jsonArray = valorPorParametros del constructor; Obvio tienes que cambiar el tipo de esa variable para que coincidan es decir si ahora es JSONArray cambialo a List o ArrayList depende de como se llame su clase. List y ArrayList son tipos de listas, puedes usar cualquiera.

> Cual sería la forma de desplegar un elemento json en los TextView? Estoy seguro de que esta forma
>   .setText(objActual.getString("nombreDelElemento")) ya no sería la
>   correcta. Además, es posible enviar los valores "description" a otra
>   activity vía Intent para mostrarlos en otra pantalla?

En realidad es demasiado similar. Suponiendo que vas a crear una lista de tipo usuario, la clase usuario tiene cada propiedad del json. Por lo tanto seria similar a:

```
Usuario usuario = list.get(position);

v.nombreUsuario.setText(usuario.getName("name"));
```

Como ultima recomendación, si tienes el JSON en un variable la puedes parsear a tu objeto Usuario utilizando la librería GSON. No voy a entrar en detalles porque no es parte de la pregunta pero puede revisar el siguiente enlace [aqui](https://geekytheory.com/trabajando-con-json-en-android-gson) o algo mucho más complejo [aquí](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-gson-libreria-para-parsear-documentos-json/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Gustavo. Me quedó mucho mas claro, agradecido por los links de GSON!